# webBrowser not navigating, even when DocumentStream is set?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I'm trying to load a page in WebBrowser thorugh responseStream sent by the server. I tried setting, its DocumentStream property but the browser is not navigating. This is my code:

```
private void btnFbConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com");
        request.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        webBrowser1.DocumentStream = rdr.BaseStream;// after this line, I'm expecting the browser to display the facebook login page.
        MessageBox.Show(rdr.ReadToEnd());
        rdr.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Am I missing an intermediate step or something??? If not, what might be causing the browser not to cause navigation???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close the stream before the `WebBrowser` accesses it.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com");
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = rdr.BaseStream;// after this line, I'm expecting the browser to display the facebook login page.
MessageBox.Show(rdr.ReadToEnd());
//rdr.Close();
//response.Close();
```

Additionally, you might encounter a error because the relative path resources on the server cannot be resolved. So, I recommend you use:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.facebook.com");
```

Comment: this is just an example web address; and during runtime it'll be generated dynamically and hence change...which means I cannot use Navigate method.

Comment: @Pratik Chandra: ya, I miss you need to also comment `//MessageBox.Show(rdr.ReadToEnd())`.